# Error in adding objective-c files to firebreath. unable to call obj-c from c++

Tags: c++, objective-c, firebreath

I'm working on building a plugin for mac using Firebreath, I coded in c++ so far, but i want to use obj-c too. I'm new to objective c and Firebreath.I have no clue how to add .m or .mm files. please tell me how to do this, I need to call the functions written in objective c from c++ using firebreath.

Answer (score 2):

This is the basic flow i know off.

Objective C  ->  .mm file implementation -> c++ calls.

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly unrelated to firebreath, it's more a question of how to use objective c++ and c++ in the same project.

Basic rules of thumb:

- To include a .m or .mm file in the project, just configure cmake to include them.  it'll do the rest.
- You cannot include any objective c/c++ code in a .h file that will be included by normal .c or .cpp files unless you protect it with `#ifdef __OBJC__`
- You *can* use objective C from a c++ class inside a .mm file
- Basically what you're doing is creating a c++ class that can be used by other cpp files but wraps the objective c functionality that you need.  Anything that must be in the .h file that is specific to obj c goes in the `#ifdef` and everything else is in the .mm file

Hope that helps.  See [WebViewMac.h](https://github.com/firebreath/FireBreath/blob/master/src/libs/WebView/Mac/WebViewMac.h) and [WebViewMac.mm](https://github.com/firebreath/FireBreath/blob/master/src/libs/WebView/Mac/WebViewMac.mm) in the [FireBreath source](https://github.com/firebreath/FireBreath/) for an example of this technique.